# Add specific price to Product Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, admin, price

I need to create a module in prestashop 1.7.3 to make available wholesale prices. The main idea: There are 3 types of prices in cart: retail price, small_wholesale price and BIG_wholesale price. I need to add small_wholesale price and big_wholesale price fields to my product and allow admin to add product and set them in prices tab(below retail price). Actually it's easy to create extra database fields in product table what i did, but still don't know what to override to create fields in product creation page, it should look like this.
[image]

Comment: Why do not use a new customer's group and add price rules for it? What you have posted there isn't possible to achieve with overrides only.

Comment: thanks, i changed the idea